# How make my API knows the IP of the client, to make a socket communication

Tags: java, android, sockets

I'm developing an android application, and I'm stuck with the notification's thing. The users can be able to like images from other users. When it happens, the user who receive the like have to get a notification. To do that, on the client application, I have a service always running on the foreground and ServerSocket listening. On the other hand, I develop an API which insert the likes on the database. In my opinion, is At that moment when my API have to use a socket to communicate with the client. The problem is that I need the IP of the client to do that. One way to do it would be when the users log in the application save on the database their IP, and when they log out deleted it. I don't know if the IP of a mobile phone is always the same..... in this case it would work, but I don't know if is a good practice...
Somebody knows a better way to do that?

Comment: You cannot simply use their IP to connect to a client, especially if that client is a mobile phone which a) never has an own ip but is always on some private network and b) hopefully does not have any open ports. The phone has to poll for changes to some API.

Comment: If you have a server running on a mobile phone with mobile connection(not wifi) then your server is nor reachable from internet as most mobile providers block incoming connections.

Comment: thanks, @f1sh, blackapps. Then, how people do that kind of things? I suppose that one way to do that is make the client execute requests, to the server, with volley all the time.... but, it doesn't look good in terms of performance....